# Is it possible to have Angular consume Joomla pages?

Tags: javascript, php, angular, joomla

I'm in a situation where I need to integrate Joomla in an Angular app. I don't have much experience with Joomla and believe that I can use it as a headless CMS to get content Data with JSON. I however also need to be able to allow other people to just create pages/templates using Joomla and update the navigation of my Angular app with those newly created Pages.

Is something like this possible?